# Tensorflow object detection: export inference graph

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, miniconda

I have an error in exporting an inference graph and I searched for hours but can't find a solution; this is my error:

**Command:**
    python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training "model.ckpt-2950" --output_directory export

**Error Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "export_inference_graph.py", line 151, in 
tf.app.run()
File "C:\Users\OctaNet\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
File "export_inference_graph.py", line 135, in main
text_format.Merge(f.read(), pipeline_config)
File "C:\Users\OctaNet\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 125, in read
self._preread_check()
File "C:\Users\OctaNet\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 85, in _preread_check
compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
File "C:\Users\OctaNet\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in exit
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: training : Acc\udce8s refus\udce9.
; Input/output error
```

Comment: Can you show us what you researched and why that didn't help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need remove : from 'training : Acc\udce8s refus\udce9'

Answer (score 0):

The `--pipeline_config_path` flag has been set to `training faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config` which is not a valid path due to the space character following the word `training`.

Perhaps user11095295 intended to write `training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config`.